# HTML5 / CSS How to code a Side Bar height to automatically match a wrapper height?

Tags: css, html, wrapper, sidebar

I have a sidebar code (`#leftcolumn`) written in CSS and HTML. I can't seem to match the wrapper height. I have so far tried `position:absolute;` and all but it doesn't help. There are othr methods that I have tried but non of it seems to work. The sidebar keeps showing a small area.

**The Code:**

```css
body {
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2eab7;
}
#wrapper {
  background-color: #ffffff; 
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto -40px;
  height: auto;
  height: 100%;
  min-width:850px;
  position: relative;
} 
#leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #dfbf9f;
}
#rightcolumn {
  margin-left: 155px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
} 
header {
  background-image:url("javalogo.gif");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color:#CCAA66;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 155px;
}
h2 {
  color: #869dc7; 
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
.content {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 20px; 
} 
#floatright {
  margin: 10px;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
footer {
  font-size:70%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  background-color:#CCAA66;
  background-position: center;
} 
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <div id="leftcolumn">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="rooms.html">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="directions.html">Directions</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <footer>Copyright &copy; 2014</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: what wrapper? i can't see wrapper in your html.

Comment: How exactly do you want to display the `#leftcolumn`?

Comment: It acts as a side bar the height should be automatically relative to the wrapper's height. The wrapper height is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle which shows your code with a full height "leftcolumn".
I've added the wrapper and made it absolutely positioned, the "leftcolumn" has a height of 100%.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7jxrbqh4/1/)

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftcolumn">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="rooms.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="directions.html">Directions</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
body {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f2eab7;
}

#wrapper {
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto -40px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-width:850px;
    position: fixed;
} 

#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #dfbf9f;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: It exceeds the wrapper original padding size.

Answer (score 0):

try this **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLorjxxo/)**

**CSS**

```
#leftcolumn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #dfbf9f;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```